# PySimpleGUI and custom usb joystick input

Tags: python, pysimplegui, evdev

I am trying to make an arcade style user guided story book terminal using PySimpleGUI and a custom made usb joystick providing the input. I have created a PySimpleGUI imageloader with the button prompts.
Image viewer:

```
import io
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("/path/to/file.jpg")
image.thumbnail((200, 200))
bio = io.BytesIO()
image.save(bio, format="PNG")

layout = [[sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-")],
          [sg.Button("Green"),
           sg.Button("Blue"),]
          ]
window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout, finalize=True)
window["-IMAGE-"].update(data=bio.getvalue())

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Green":
        load_image_str = "g"
    if event == "Blue":
        load_image_str = "b"

    file_path = ("/path/to/folder" + load_image_str + ".jpg")

    if os.path.exists(file_path) and file_path.endswith('.jpg'):
        image = Image.open("/path/to/file")
        image.thumbnail((400, 400))
        bio = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(bio, format="PNG")
        window["-IMAGE-"].update(data=bio.getvalue())

window.close()
```

Joystick input

```
from evdev import InputDevice, ecodes

#Button codes
greenBtn = 288
blueBtn = 289

device = InputDevice('/dev/input/eventXX')

def main():
    for event in device.read_loop():
        if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
            if event.value == 1:
                if event.code == greenBtn:
                    print("green")
                if event.code == blueBtn:
                    print("blue")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x =main()
```

The image viewer and the joystick are working as I expected but I don't know where to even start combining the two. Am I on the right track here or should I be looking at a different way to do this?

Comment: A good way of going about this would be to run the joystick code as a thread.  The thread can communicate with your GUI by sending messages by calling  the `write_event_value` method.  There are a lot of examples you'll find in the demo programs and in the ecookbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a thread for the joystick part, then your GUI can wait on Joystick events and handle them or handle events from the GUI itself.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import random

# thread for joystick handling
def joystick_thread(window):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)                # Replace with your read joystick code

        # If got some kind of joystick event
        value = random.randint(200, 250)
        window.write_event_value(('-JOYSTICK-', '-EV KEY-'), value)

# The GUI Portion
def main():
    layout = [  [sg.Text('Joystick Monitor Window')],
                [sg.Text(key='-OUT-')],
                [sg.Button('Does Nothing'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

    window = sg.Window('Joystick', layout, finalize=True)
    
    # Startup the joystick thread
    window.start_thread(lambda: joystick_thread(window), ('-JOYSTICK-', '-ENDED-'))

    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break

        if event[0] == '-JOYSTICK-':
            if event[1] == '-ENDED-':
                break
            if event[1] == '-EV KEY-':
                window['-OUT-'].update(f'Joystick event received {values[event]}')
    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: It took while to get it working but the trick was to test {values[event]} in an if statement - thanks

Comment: ✅ Awesome to hear!  G'luck with the project.